# How to fetch firestore data correctly?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have 2 collections in Firestore:

**1. User Following:**

Structure: "Users" -> "User UID" -> "User Following" -> "Following User UID"

User following includes user data that the current user is following

**2. Videos:**

Structure: "Videos" -> "Video Id"

Videos include video uploaded by different users across platform

What I am trying now is to show videos uploaded by following users. I successfully managed to fetch following user ids using the code below:

```
Context context;
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

public UserVideoAdapter(@NonNull @NotNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FollowList> options, Context context) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull UserVideoAdapter.UserVideoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull FollowList model) {

    String userId = model.getUserId(); // Following user ids

}

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Override
public UserVideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_cell, parent, false);
    return new UserVideoHolder(v);
}

public static class UserVideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout videoContainer, mainContainerVideo;
    CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    TextView videoTitle;
    ImageView videoImageView;

    public UserVideoHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mainContainerVideo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainContainerVideo);
        videoContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
        userProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userProfileImage);
        videoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoTitle);
        videoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to fetch videos corresponding to every users that I follow. So far I have tried many methods but got no results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit:

Video collection:

[image]

User Following collection:

[image]

FollowList query:

```
private void setUpVideoRV() {
    final CollectionReference followingRef = db.collection("Users").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).collection("User Following");
    
    Query query = followingRef.orderBy("userId", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FollowList> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FollowList>()
            .setQuery(query, FollowList.class)
            .build();

    userHomeVideoAdapter = new UserHomeVideoAdapter(options, getContext());

    LinearLayoutManager videoLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    videoRV.setLayoutManager(videoLM);
    videoRV.setAdapter(userHomeVideoAdapter);
    userHomeVideoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

UserHomeVideoAdapter.java:

```
Query query = db.collection("Videos").whereEqualTo("publisherId", model.getUserId());

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->  {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (task.getResult() != null) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Video video = documentSnapshot.toObject(Video.class);

                    thumbUrl = video.getThumbUrl();
                    videoTitle = video.getVideoTitle();
                    videoUrl = video.getVideoUrl();
                    videoDesc = video.getVideoDesc();
                    videoId = video.getVideoId();
                    publisherId = video.getPublisherId();

                    Log.d("VideoId", videoId);
                }

                if (task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                    db.collection("Users").document(model.getUserId()).get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                        if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                            final User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                            if (user != null) {
                                if (user.getUserImageUrl() == null) {
                                    holder.userProfileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                } else {
                                    Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(user.getUserImageUrl())).into(holder.userProfileImage);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

                    Glide.with(context).load(thumbUrl).into(holder.videoImageView);
                    holder.videoTitle.setText(videoTitle);
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                    holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("videoPublisherUserName", model.getUserName());
        intent.putExtra("thumbUrl", thumbUrl);
        intent.putExtra("videoUrl", videoUrl);
        intent.putExtra("videoPublisherEmail", model.getUserEmail());
        intent.putExtra("videoId", videoId);
        intent.putExtra("videoPublisherFullName", model.getUserFullName());
        intent.putExtra("videoPublisherId", publisherId);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(position));

        Log.d("DATA", "thumbUrl" + " => " + thumbUrl + " videoUrl" + " => " + videoUrl + " videoId" + " => " + videoId + " publisherId" + " => " + publisherId);
    });
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Besides that, how do you query the database?

Comment: I don't see any Firestore query here..!!

Comment: @AlexMamo I added all of them to my edit now

Comment: @FlyingDutchman Now I added it to my edit

Comment: As I see, you are using the Firebase-UI library. You cannot pass two queries to the FirestoreRecyclerOptions, only one is allowed. However, you can achieve that by querying the database twice, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried to query Videos using model.getUserId() but it seems to have some strange behaviors. I added it above can you please check and suggest if it is right way to do it or not. Note: By strange behavior I mean my onClick opens only the last returned video inside for loop

Comment: That's normal behavior since you doing that in a loop.

Comment: @AlexMamo then how can i assign my data to items based on positions as to when I click on my itemView it will open the video based on position but not only the last one.

Comment: can you describe the weird behaviors that you are getting, are you getting an error?